# Query for determining what UserRoles are available under a given UserLicense

Tags: roles

I am using Salesforce API to create new SF user accounts with a particular Profile and User role.  SF API provides a straight forward way of using the UserLicense to determine what Profiles apply under a given license.  However it is unclear to me how to determine what UserRoles are available under a given license. When creating a new user Account manually using the Salesforce portal, there is even a tip next to the Role field that says that user roles are determined based on the user license - how would you do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

I might be reading your question wrong, but I don't think there is a direct relationship between UserRole and UserLicense like there is between Profile and UserLicense.

The [User, Sharing, and Permission Objects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_users.htm) data model might help here.

[image: User, Sharing, and Permission Objects Data Model]

Comment: but under some user licenses you can not assign any roles.

Comment: but under some user licenses you can not assign any roles. When you go to create a user manually, there is an info msg next to the role that says: "Depends on License". Furthermore, when I create a guest user via SF api, I get an error back that guest users cannot have a role. So how can I tell which licenses support user roles?

Comment: You might need to build a manual lookup from the UserLicense.LicenseDefinitionKey to indicate if Roles are supported. I know this isn't ideal, but I can't see any clear indication of Role applicability for user licenses.